# How to access an API endpoint through a token using headers?

Tags: node.js, api, express, authentication, bearer-token

Currently I have a public api implemented, anyone can access it.

My intention is that the user now pass a token through the header so that they can access the data from the endpoints. But I don't know how to implement it in my code.

I appreciate your help!

```js
router.get('/AllReports' , (req , res) =>{
  PluginManager.reports()
    .then(reports =>{
      res.status(200).json({
        reports
      });
    }).catch((err) =>{
      console.error(err);
    });
});
```

**app.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const helmet = require('helmet');
const cors = require('cors');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const middlewares = require('./middlewares/index').middleware;
const api = require('./api');

const app = express();

app.use(morgan('dev'));
app.use(helmet());
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));


app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.json({
    message: '✨✨'
  });
});

app.use('/api/v1', api);

app.use(middlewares);

module.exports = app;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To see a list of HTTP request headers, you can use :

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(req.headers));
```

Then you can check if token is valid and then

go on with processing.

Example

```
router.get('/', (req, res) => {

  // header example with get
  const authHeader = req.get('Authorization');  //specific header
  console.log(authHeader);
  // example with headers object.  // headers object
  console.log(req.headers);

});
```

Comment: Could you present an example inside router.get?

Comment: Updated my answer.